# How to get a telegram private channel messages with telethon

Tags: python, telethon

i use this code but get me public Channels Messages only

```py
async def read_chat_by_id(chat_id, limit):
    try:
        await client.start(PHONE_NUMBER)

        # Get the chat entity using the chat ID
        entity = await client.get_entity(chat_id)

        if entity:
            # Get the messages from the chat
            messages = await client.get_messages(entity, limit=limit)

            # Print the messages
            for message in messages:
                print(f"Message ID: {message.id}, From: {message.from_id.user_id}, Text: {message.message}")
        else:
            print(f"Chat with ID {chat_id} not found.")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
    finally:
        await client.disconnect()
```

i don't know i need help

Comment: where exactly are you stuck ?  what is the problem ?

Comment: how to ask a good question:
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)